# Convert excelsheet columns format in php not working

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am working on `staff attendance`. User can upload an attendance sheet and my system will give the view of attendance excel sheet to user and then he can save it to database. The values from excel sheet saving successfully in database.

The problem is user can add record in columns of excel sheet in any format but when I get in PHP the date format goes wrong.

**e.g.**
when user add attendance date in column, the format of column is `date` and when he can save in out time it may be number format and when user upload this excel sheet, the date preview gone in `unix time stamp`.

> Here is examples in images

1. **Date in Excel sheet**
   [image]

   2. **Time in and out in excel sheet**
      [image]
   3. **When user go to site and upload this excel sheet**
      [image]
   4. **Then a popup window open**
      [image]
   5. **Then user browses the excel sheet and then I show the excel sheet view, that viewing wrong**
      [image]

You can see in above image that the date is being converted in unix time stamp and time in and out in numeric.

> I want this view when a user can upload an excel sheet.

[image]

So hope you understand my issue and what I want.

Here is my upload and view excel sheet code:

```
$excel_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$target = SERVERPATH . 'assets/attendance_excel/';
$ext = pathinfo($excel_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$filename = rand() . date("YmdHis");

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target . $filename . '.' . $ext);

include(EXCEL_CLASS);

$inputFileName = $target . $filename . '.' . $ext;
//            chmod($inputFileName,0777);

try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
//            $objWorksheet->getStyle('A1:E433')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('Text');

$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestDataRow();

$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5


$td_data = '';
$row_no = 0;

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    $check_empty_column = 0;

    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        if ($objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() == null) {
           $check_empty_column++;
      }
    }

    if ($check_empty_column < $highestColumnIndex) {
       for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {

           $td_data .= '<td>' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>';

       }
    }

    $tr_data[$row_no] = $td_data;
    $td_data = '';
    $row_no++;
}

$data_all = array(
     'data' => $tr_data,
     't_col' => $highestColumnIndex,
     'name' => $filename . '.' . $ext
);
echo json_encode($data_all);
```

I also search a lot about this and found something like this `setFormatCode`, `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL` etc but its not working for me. I try my best.

So please give me solution for this problem.

> **Note:** I can not restrict a user that he convert the columns and than add data.

Hope you understand my question

Answer (score 2):

MS Excel stores dates as a float value, a serialized timestamp, the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if the file is using the Mac Calendar), and it is the number format mask for the cell that displays it as a formatted date.

PHPExcel provides a series of methods for converting between that MS Exce serialized timestamp and unix timestamps or PHP DateTime objects

```
$unixTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($excelTimestampValue);
```

will convert the MS Excel timestamp to a Unix timestamp

```
$phpDateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($excelTimestampValue);
```

will convert the MS Excel timestamp to a PHP DateTime object

And you can then use PHP's standard `date()` function or the DateTime object's `format()` method to format that value however you like.

```
$excelTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($phpDateTimeObject);
$excelTimestamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($unixTimestamp);
```

will convert either a unix timestamp or a PHPP DateTime object to an MS Excel serialized timestamp value

If you want to change the way that an MS Excel serialized timestamp is displayed in a spreadsheet, then you need to use an Excel format mask that corresponds too a date/time mask.... PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL is ***not*** a format mask for dates/times

Comment: please can you tell me how can I do this in my code ... because I got all columns and rows dynamically

Comment: As you know which cells contain dates, then you retrieve the cell value using `$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue()` and pass the result as an argument to `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()`, retrieving that result, then using the DateTime object's `format()` method to tell it how you want to display the result

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `getFormattedValue()` rather than `getValue()` to tell PHPExcel to return the result pre-formatted according to the number format mask that has been set in the spreadsheet itself

Comment: thanx ... your second comment works for me ... perfectly ... you edit your answer ... so that i can accept this